# Find the complex roots in exponential equations or trigonometric

Tags: python, sage

If you could help me with the code in sage.
I want to find the roots of the equations of this type: `e^(2*pi*b*i)`. With a constant `b` and the imaginary unit `i`.
This equation can also be written as: `cos(b*2*pi)+ i*sin(b*2*pi)`. Do you know any command to do this?

I´m trying with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cmath
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
z=var('z')
a = cos(4*cmath.pi*z)+ cos(14*cmath.pi*z) + cos(62*cmath.pi*z)+ (I* 
(sin(4*cmath.pi*z)+ sin(14*cmath.pi*z)+ sin(62*cmath.pi*z)))
def f(x):
    return np.abs( math.cos(4*math.pi*x)+ math.cos(14*math.pi*x) + 
    math.cos(62*math.pi*x)+(1j*(math.sin(4*math.pi*x)+ 
    math.sin(14*math.pi*x)+ math.sin(62*math.pi*x))))
    x = fsolve(f, 0.01)
```

also with:

```
from sage.rings.polynomial.complex_roots import complex_roots
x=polygen(CC)
complex_roots(cos(4*math.pi*x)+ cos(14*math.pi*x) + cos(62*math.pi*x)+(I* 
(sin(4*math.pi*x)+ sin(14*math.pi*x)+ sin(62*math.pi*x))))
```

Thank you!

Comment: The subject line says that you are looking for complex roots, so what do you mean by "roots in an interval"? Is `x` real or complex?

Comment: Oh sorry, x is complex. I mean the complex root of that equation, but there are more than one.

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean you want to solve equations of the form a sum of terms like `e^(i*pi*b*x)` equal zero for the variable `x`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for solutions of the equation `e^z=0` then there are none. It does not matter if z is real, purely imaginary (like `2*b*pi*i`) or arbitrarily complex.

You can see that easily if you decompose `e^z=e^(a+ib)=e^a*e^(ib)`. The second factor `e^(ib)` lies on the unit circle in the complex plane. The first factor is real and always greater than zero. The product can therefore never be zero.